# Date range query ignoring month spanning year end and year beginning

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to construct a date range query to find events.
Some of the events repeat every year (yearly_natural = true) and this causes problems when they span the year end/ beginning. I need to know how to store these dates(what value do I use for year?) and/or improve the query.
I am currently storing repeating dates as date type with year 2017 (or 2017 and 2018 if they span the new year)
This is what I have tried. It works apart from when an event runs across the new year. Only the relevant fields are included in this question.
I am happy to redesign the database as I only have a small amount of test data

```
"SELECT event.event_name, event.start_date, event.end_date, event.all_year, event.yearly_natural 
      FROM event
      INNER JOIN event_location ON event_location.event_location_id = event.event_location_id
      WHERE 

      (event.yearly_natural = false

      AND
            (event.start_date BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo') 
            OR (event.end_date BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo') 
            OR (event.start_date <= '$testFrom' AND event.end_date >= '$testTo')
           )    
      OR (event.yearly_natural = true
      AND 
          (DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, '%m%d') BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo')
          OR  (DATE_FORMAT(event.end_date, '%m%d') BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo')
          OR (DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, '%m%d') <= '$testFrom' AND event.end_date >= '$testTo')
          )  

      OR (event.all_year = true)

          ";
```

Comment: Weird. I would think it to be unlikely that an event starts and ends on the same dates each year and take place in the same location. I would make two tables, one for the event properties, like name, description, etc, and one for the event dates and location. So you would make a new row in the last table for each time an event takes place. This way you can keep using the `date` type.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hi. The events are wildlife events eg seasonal flowering or bird roosting hence same date and location. There are already two tables (event and event_location)hence the join but I have ommited the location details for clarity.

Comment: So my problem is: what if one of these events runs from November to January every year...how do I store the dates or query them?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ...but I see your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment by KIKO Software. It probably makes more sense to have one entry per occurrence of event. However, if you want to keep it the way you have it, you could probably do this. The concept is that you modify the year input dates to match the year of the stored dates, and then compare them as whole dates instead of just month and day. Not sure if it will work 100% as-is or if it will need some tweaking, but you should be able to get something working from here.

```
     (event.yearly_natural = false

  AND
        (event.start_date BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo') 
        OR (event.end_date BETWEEN '$testFrom' AND '$testTo') 
        OR (event.start_date <= '$testFrom' AND event.end_date >= '$testTo')
       )    
  OR (event.yearly_natural = true
  AND 
      (event.start_date BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testFrom', '%m-%d')) AND CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testTo', '%m-%d')))
    OR (event.end_date BETWEEN CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.end_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testFrom', '%m-%d')) AND CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.end_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testTo', '%m-%d')))
    OR (event.start_date <= CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.start_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testFrom', '%m-%d')) AND event.end_date >= CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(event.end_date, '%Y'), '-', DATE_FORMAT('$testTo', '%m-%d'))
)  

  OR (event.all_year = true)
```

Comment: Thanks. Give me a while to try this out and I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Gentlemen, Thank you both. After a while considering this, I think that you are both correct in suggesting that I should store each occurence as a separate entry and I shall go with this. However, I am indebted for the insights that you have both provided with the 'daystamp' and concatenation which have increased my knowledge. This is my first sucessfully posted SO question so how do I give you both SO kudos?

Comment: @silverbadger You can upvote both answers by clicking the up arrow next to them (if you feel they both are valuable). If you ended up using one as your solution, you should probably also mark it as the accepted answer (click the check mark). If you didn't end up using either answer, you could either mark whichever one you feel is best or comes closest, or  you could even provide your own answer, describing in detail what you did.

Comment: Thanks. I lack the reputation to vote so only kudos to one despite both being valuable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could simply choose an arbitary date, say January 1st, and assign it the value of 0. The 5th of January would be 4 and the 3th of January next year would be 367, and so on. Similar to what a Linux timestamp does, so let's call it a 'daystamp'. Note that these daystamps are relative, not absolute like the timestamps. The only thing you need to make is the conversion routines from real dates to these daystamps. I would do this in PHP:

```
function daystamp2timestamp($daystamp)
// returns a timestamp of the daystamp
{
  $startThisYear = strtotime(date('Y').'-01-01 12:00');
  return strtotime("+$daystamp day",$startThisYear);
} 

function timestamp2daystamp($timestamp)
// returns a daystamp of the timestamp 
{
  $startThisYear = strtotime(date('Y').'-01-01 12:00');
  return floor(($timestamp-$startThisYear)/(24*60*60));
}
```

This code is untested, so test it before using it. It's just there to give you an idea. As you probably know `timestamp` can easily be converted to dates with the `date()` function.

You would only store daystamps in your database, and with them it easy to see if an events falls within a date range. First convert the dates to daystamps and compare those with the values in the database.